# Collapsible with Image Padding:0 Margin:0 Top: 0 Left:0

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make a collapsible with an image, to look like a listview. So, that the photo is close to the top:0, left:0;, no margin, no padding.

```
.ui-collapsible div ul .ui-corner-top, .ui-collapsible div ul .ui-corner-bottom {
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding:0px !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/vM4R5/

I tried many options and didn't manage to figure it out

thanks
Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQM renders a button with padding within the collapsible heading, try the following CSS:

```
 .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn-inner{
     margin: 0px !important;
     padding:0px !important;
 }
```

Here is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/vM4R5/1/